# LCD backlight LED voltage. Insignia (Sharp) Model NS-32D20SNA14

Tags: arduino, voltage

I have a TV LED back light panel from Insignia (Sharp) Model NS-32D20SNA14

I have isolated the back frame with the LED panel. The power clip is intact. Everything else is removed.

Using a VOM to get the total R of the circuit, how do I figure out the lowest voltage to illuminate the panel. All other circuitry has been removed. The LCD screen was broken.

I am an amateur with the least bit of electronics training.

Thank you for anything that comes to (your) mind.

Answer (score 2):

PLEASE READ MY **COMPLETE** ANSWER CAREFULLY BEFORE ATTEMPTING TO POWER YOUR LEDS, OR YOU WILL VERY LIKELY BURN THEM OUT! If anything is unclear, ask before making a big mistake!

You can't determine the forward voltage of an LED by measuring its resistance, plus you don't have sufficient voltage to measure it with an ohmmeter.
 LEDs are diodes, and as such they are NON-LINEAR, which means that the current through them does not rise proportionally with the voltage across them like it does in resistors (which are LINEAR devices).
 A single WHITE LED (such as the ones in your TV backlight panel) needs about 2.7V to 3.4V (depending on the semiconductor material used) to turn on, and TV panels almost always employ multiple LEDs in series, so the simplest thing for you to do is count the number of LEDs conected in series, multiply by 2.7V and you would get get the lowest voltage needed to turn them on.
 Be aware that not all of the LEDs may be in series. They are sometimes connected as two or more series strings in parallel with each other.
Additionaly, you MUST KNOW that you CAN NOT use voltage to drive LEDs, because their forward voltage depends on their temperature (higher temperature - lower voltage) and current through them (higher current - slightly higher voltage), and the MUST be either driven by a constant current source (not a constant voltage source) or have their current limited with a resistor.

Another way to determine the LED (multiple LEDs in series) voltage is by supplying it with a relatively high voltage (10V to 40V) through a relatively high resistance resistor (like 10k-47k for example) and measuring the voltage across the LED terminals when the LED lights up.
Just  BE CAREFUL not to blind yourself! You could turn the LEDs away from you, or cover them with a non-transparent material to protect your eyes.